# JSDOM is not loading JavaScript included with <script> tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

**Note:** This question is not a duplicate of other existing questions because this question does not use `jsdom.env()` function call which older version of JSDOM use.

File `bar.js`:

```
console.log('bar says: hello')
```

File `foo.js`:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom')
var html = '<!DOCTYPE html><head><script src="bar.js"></script></head><body><div>Foo</div></body>'
var window = new jsdom.JSDOM(html).window
window.onload = function () {
  console.log('window loaded')
}
```

When I run `foo.js`, I get this output.

```
$ node foo.js
window loaded
```

Why did `bar says: hello` output did not come? It looks like `bar.js` was not loaded. How can I make `jsdom` load the file in the `script` tag?

**[EDIT/SOLUTION]:** Problem solved after following a suggestion in the answer by Quentin. This code works:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom')
var html = '<!DOCTYPE html><head><script src="bar.js"></script></head><body><div>Foo</div></body>'
var window = new jsdom.JSDOM(html, { runScripts: "dangerously", resources: "usable" }).window
window.onload = function () {
  console.log('window loaded')
}
```

Comment: @rlemon I don't see how this is a duplicate of that question. That question uses `jsdom.env()`. This one does not. How is that answer applicable here?

Comment: @Lone_learner : I installed jdsom jsdom@16.4.0, copied your code into relevant `bar.js` and `foo.js` but I'am unable to reproduce your scenario. It only returns `window loaded` but not `bar says: hello`. Is the code above missing some settings or code ?

Comment: I found another thread which point toward server loading of the .js files. https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1914 . I'am still curious to know if Lone_Learner & @Quentin found simpler way.

Comment: "EDIT/SOLUTION" should be posted as an answer, not an edit to the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to [the JSDOM homepage](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom).

Skim the headings until you find one marked [Executing scripts](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#executing-scripts)

> To enable executing scripts inside the page, you can use the
>   `runScripts: "dangerously"` option:
>
> ```
> const dom = new JSDOM(`<body>
>   <script>document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));</script>
> </body>`, { runScripts: "dangerously" });
>
> // The script will be executed and modify the DOM:
> dom.window.document.body.children.length === 2;
> ```
>
> Again we emphasize to only use this when feeding jsdom code you know
>   is safe. If you use it on arbitrary user-supplied code, or code from
>   the Internet, you are effectively running untrusted Node.js code, and
>   your machine could be compromised.
>
> If you want to execute external scripts, included via `<script
>   src="">`, you'll also need to ensure that they load them. To do this,
>   add the option `resources: "usable"` as [described below](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#loading-subresources).

Answer (score 2):

Given I was unable to reproduce the `url`-based solution from the code above...

### Brutal bundle alternative : inline it all !

Read the various `.js` files, inject them as string into the html page. Then wait the page to load as in a normal navigator.
These libraries are loaded into `_window = new JSDOM(html, { options }).window;` and therefor available to your node script.

This is likely to prevent you from doing xhr calls and therefore only partially solve the issue.

say-hello.js

```js
// fired when loaded
console.log("say-hello.js says: hello!")
// defined and needing a call
var sayBye = function(name) { 
    var name = name ||'Hero!'; 
    console.log("say-hello.js says: Good bye! "+name)
}
```

main.js:

```js
    const fs    = require("fs");
    const jsdom = require("jsdom");
    const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
    
    var NAME  = process.env.NAME; // variable from terminal

    var html = '<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><body><div>Foo</div></body>'
    var _window = new JSDOM(html, {
        runScripts: "dangerously",
        resources: "usable" }).window;
    /* ************************************************************************* */
    /* Add scripts to head ***************************************************** */
    var jsFiles = [
        'say-hello.js'
    ];
    var scriptsContent = ``;
    for(var i =0; i< jsFiles.length;i++){
        console.log(__dirname + '/'+ jsFiles[i])
      let scriptContent = fs.readFileSync( jsFiles[i], 'utf8');
      scriptsContent = scriptsContent + `
      /* ******************************************************************************************* */
      /* `+jsFiles[i]+` **************************************************************************** */
      `+scriptContent;
    };
    let scriptElement = _window.document.createElement('script');
    scriptElement.textContent = scriptsContent;
    _window.document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);


/* ************************************************************************* */
/* Run page **************************************************************** */
_window.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    console.log('main says: DOMContentLoaded')
    // We need to delay one extra turn because we are the first DOMContentLoaded listener,
    // but we want to execute this code only after the second DOMContentLoaded listener
    // (added by external.js) fires.
    _window.sayBye(NAME); // prints "say-hello.js says: Good bye!"

  });
```

Run it:

```sh
NAME=John node main.js    # expects hello and good bye to john messages
```

Source:

- https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1914
- https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/3023

Answer (score 0):

Using JSDOM option `url : file://${__dirname}/index.html` could work, according to a [source](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/3023#issuecomment-883585057). If you test it, please report result here.