# How to load script that uses `window` object in jsdom (jest)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, jsdom

I am a beginner to `jest`, not sure how do I test a script that's suppossed to be run in the dom, if possible I don't want to load the dom, just `app.env.js`

- app.env.js

```js
window.APP_ENV = Object.freeze({
  env: "test",
});
```

Test passes, so is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53069500/jsdom-is-not-loading-javascript-included-with-script-tag) the proper way to do it?

- app.env.test.js

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

var { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");

test("Contains environment", () => {
  var html =
    '<!DOCTYPE html><head><script src="app.env.js"></script></head><body><div>Foo</div></body>';

  var dom = new JSDOM(html, {
    runScripts: "dangerously",
    resources: "usable",
  });

  dom.onload = () => {
    expect(dom.window.APP_ENV).toBe("local");
  };
});
```

Asking because when I run jest, the file doesn't appear in the table of files

```sh
jest --coverage --passWithNoTests
 PASS  env/app.env.test.js
  ✓ Contains environment (26 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.66 s, estimated 1 s
```

But if i do the following it appears

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

var { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
import scriptCode from "./app.env.js";

test("Contains environment", () => {
  console.log("scriptCode: ", scriptCode);

  var html =
    '<!DOCTYPE html><head><script src="app.env.js"></script></head><body><div>Foo</div></body>';

  var dom = new JSDOM(html, {
    runScripts: "dangerously",
    resources: "usable",
  });

  dom.onload = () => {
    expect(dom.window.APP_ENV).toBe("local");
  };
});
```

Here is the log of the last command

```js
jest --coverage --passWithNoTests
  console.log
    scriptCode:  {}

      at Object.<anonymous> (env/app.env.test.js:9:11)

 PASS  env/app.env.test.js
  ✓ Contains environment (39 ms)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 app.env.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.65 s, estimated 1 s
```